# Como enviar variáveis para outra page, no Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone, xaml, windows-phone-8-1

Tentei seguir [esse método](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff626521(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_PassingParameters), mas ocorre um erro na MainPage, dizendo que o `NavigationService` não existe no contexto atual.

Na BlankPage, o mesmo erro ocorre no `NavigationContext`.

Como posso solucionar isso? Preciso importar alguma biblioteca, assim como é no Android?

Pelo que entendi, esse método é para enviar `strings`. Como envio variáveis do tipo `int` e `double`?

Segue o código:

**MainPage.xaml:**

```
<Grid>
    <TextBlock x:Name="helloMessage" Margin="10,132,10,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Hello" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="26.667" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light"/>
    <Button x:Name="sayHelloButton" Content="Say Hello!" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10,64,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="sayHelloButton_Click"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="nameField" Margin="10,10,10,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Enter your name..." VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="39"/>
    <Button x:Name="button_GoToPage" Content="Go to page" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,159,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="button_GoToPage_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs:**

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

namespace MyApp
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {

        string texto1 = "Hello World!";

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
        }

        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void sayHelloButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            helloMessage.Text = "Hello, "+nameField.Text+"!";
        }

        private void button_GoToPage_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/BlankPage.xaml?msg=" + nameField.Text, UriKind.Relative));
;       }
    }
}
```

**BlankPage.xaml:**

```
<Page
x:Class="MyApp.BlankPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:MyApp"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

<Grid>
    <AppBarButton x:Name="appBarButton" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Icon="Back" Label="" Margin="-10,-2,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="appBarButton_Click"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="textName1" Margin="10,98,10,492" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="(vazio)" FontSize="32" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>

</Grid>
```

**BlankPage.xaml.cs:**

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

namespace MyApp
{
    public sealed partial class BlankPage : Page
    {

        public BlankPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            /// Manter página armazenada em cache, mesmo utilizando o botão voltar
            this.NavigationCacheMode = Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation.NavigationCacheMode.Enabled;
        }

        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

            string msg = "";

            if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("msg", out msg))

                textName1.Text = msg;
        }

        private void appBarButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Frame.GoBack();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar o `System.IO.IsolatedStorage` (para uma aplicação Windows Phone Silverlight) ou `Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.` (para uma aplicação Windows Phone).

Ambas podem ser usadas em qualquer página. Sei que parece estranho você incluir as informações que precisa passar de uma página para outra em um destes *Storage*, que são de acesso global da aplicação, mas tive esta mesma dúvida sua no passado e me recomendaram esta maneira.

## Para uma aplicação "Windows Phone"

Acessar o `localSettings`:

```
var localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
```

Exemplo para adicionar um `bool`:

```
localSettings.Values["saveLogin"] = true;
```

ou

```
localSettings.Values.Add("saveLogin", true);
```

Ler a informação:

```
var value = localSettings.Values["saveLogin"];
```

Para verificar se ela existe:

```
if(localSettings.Values.ContainsKey("saveLogin"))
```

## Para uma aplicação "Windows Phone Silverlight"

Exemplo para adicionar um `bool`:

```
IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Add("saveLogin", false);
IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Save();
```

E para obter a informação salva, já em outra página:

```
IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
bool saveLogin = (bool)settings["saveLogin"];
```

Para verificar se a informação existe antes de acessá-la:

```
IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("saveLogin")
```

Naturalmente, você pode fazer o mesmo com `int` e `double`. Usei bastante este recurso neste [pequeno projeto](https://github.com/dherik/pmadex), se quiser dar uma olhada melhor.

Comment: O Visual Studio apresenta esse erro: "O nome "IsolatedStorageSettings" não existe no contexto atual."

Comment: @EdeiltonSO, deve ser porque sua aplicação não está marcada como uma aplicação  "Windows Phone Silverlight". Vou editar minha resposta.

Comment: Muito obrigado, o primeiro método funcionou perfeitamente! :D